# How to get printed characters of Linux console at given position in C++ (or C)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, console

Suppose my whole screen (console) is filled with some text (e.g. printed through `std::cout`). How can I get some characters of this console output, e.g. in the center of screen?

In Windows I can get characters of console through [ReadConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter) function.

But how to do same thing in Linux (inside C++ (or C) code)?

Is there any easy way to do this without using extra huge libraries like `ncurses`? Maybe there are some standard Linux kernel sys-call functions to achieve this task?

I need to get console text of current running program. I.e. if inside my program I printed some text, later inside this same program I want to read parts of this printed to console text.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have that capability as part of the language and standard library.  You'd need to do it with an extra huge library like `ncurses`.

Comment: Please try to avoid the term "C/C++". There is no such languages as "C/C++", only the two separate and *very* different languages C and C++.

Comment: @Eljay Maybe there is some built-in OS system call function for doing this, i.e. some syscall implemented in Linux kernel?

Comment: This might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430983/reading-from-console-output-in-c

Comment: You will need to hook into terminal program, such as Gnome Terminal and obtain screen buffer content somehow. ncurses or VT100 won't help you at all.

Comment: @user7860670 I forgot to mention that I need to get console text of current running program, if it helps to solve task, i.e. if I printed in my C++ program some text, later in inside same program I want to get this text back at some position of console.

Comment: Then you can implement your own screen buffer and print everything through it. This is basically what ncurses does with addch + inchnstr. However note that the content that end user sees on the screen will not necessary match content of this internal buffer.

Comment: @user7860670 Is there a standard way to read any type of current console buffer? Not to make code specific only to Gnome Terminal. Any code that is generic for all kinds of terminals.

Comment: First of all there could be no current console buffer. Output may go into file or printed. On Windows they provide a nice API to work with stock console output program or its substitute, but on linux there are no such things as nice API or stock programs. So i guess each specific environment and console emulator will require specific solution.