# Set a variable from system("command") (C++)

Tags: c++

*Before nothing: I searched similar problems but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. Also please, I'm noob in C so sorry for the stupid mistakes that I can do. Thanks.*

I have a little problem with my C++ file.
What I want, is set a variable from a system("command"). I don't know if I'm explaining myself well so I put my file as an example.
This is my file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int kernel = system("uname -a");
    //Here It should print the value but instead of that prints a zero :/
    printf("%d \n", kernel);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to define the variable "kernel" from the output of system("uname -a") command that should be something like:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.0.0-27-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 03:00:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However, when I try to execute the code the output is just:

`0`

I'm missing something or this cannot be done in C++? Sorry for the noob question.

Best regards.

Comment: `system()` returns the exit code, it doesn't return the output.

Comment: `system()` returns return status of the command (0 in this case). To capture its output, you need to redirect its output. As much as I hate to say it, `boost::process` is probably your friend in this case.

Comment: have a look at [`boost::process`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/process.html)

Comment: I see.. So what will be the best alternative? Save the output into a txt and then read the variable from it?
Regards and thanks for you quickly response :).
EDIT: Just saw the other comments. Going to take a look. Thanks to all.

Comment: Okey. Sorry. I will update it.

Comment: You want `popen` rather than `system`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use other function because system only return the code returned by the execution of the program. For example `boost::process`, this is a simple example

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

using namespace boost::process;

int main()
{
    ipstream pipe_stream;
    child c("gcc --version", std_out > pipe_stream);

    std::string line;

    while (pipe_stream && std::getline(pipe_stream, line) && !line.empty())
        std::cerr << line << std::endl;

    c.wait();
}
```

Example taken from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/process.html

Comment: Muchas Gracias :).

Comment: trying to use boot/process I get errors. I added them in OP.

Comment: Try to add `#include <iostream> `.

Comment: Now the error is different.
I updated the OP.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`system` returns the error code, not a command output. 0 means no error. What you are looking for is `popen`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char uname[1024];

FILE* fp = popen("uname -a", "r");
if (!fp)
    /* Handle error */;

if (fgets(uname, sizeof(uname), fp) != 0)
    std::cout << uname << std::endl;

int status = pclose(fp);
if (status == -1) {
    /* Error reported by pclose() */
}
```

Similar question demonstrates reading output data without length limit: [popen() writes output of command executed to cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610978/popen-writes-output-of-command-executed-to-cout)

Comment: This is pretty C for a C++ question and it also only works on Linux.

Comment: @Darklighter It works not only on Linux. Mac OSX, Windows have `popen`/`_popen` too. Where have you seen `uname -a` on Windows?

Comment: Thanks, this works in C but needs modifications.
Regards.

Comment: @273K what if my command output is an integer for example? It looks like the output of `popen` is always a `FILE *` and I am working on a problem where the output of `system` is an integer? I am also a c++ noob if you can't tell and I'm not sure where to look...

Comment: @ydd The output is a byte stream, it doesn't define what is a string or a number, the reader should convert bytes to desired types.